# mongoDB log files getlasterror: 1, w: "com.mongodb.WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE"

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

We have mongoDB master slave configuration. I updated spring mongoDB template driver to be replica aware with property com.mongodb.WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE. I am getting following error in the log file.

[conn2788271] runQuery called xxx.$cmd { getlasterror: 1, w: "com.mongodb.WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE", wtimeout: 0 }

[conn2786380] User Assertion: 14830:unrecognized getLastError mode: com.mongodb.WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE

[conn2786380] command xxx.$cmd command: { getlasterror: 1, w: "com.mongodb.WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE", wtimeout: 0 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:182 0ms

Seems that error is coming from this file
https://bitbucket.org/wesc/debian-mongodb/src/97846fbc9d31/mongodb-2.0.2/db/repl_block.cpp

Any clues if I am missing something?

Comment: I tried to change the property to int value 2 instead of constant, but still it is producing Asserts in the logs.

Comment: The solution for this was to construct new bean    <bean id="xxxWriteConcern" class="com.mongodb.WriteConcern">
        <constructor-arg type="int" name="w" value="1"/>
    </bean> and give the ref of the above bean to <bean id="xxxMongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="xxxMongoDbFactory"/>
        <property name="writeConcern" ref="xxxWriteConcern"/>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the integer 1 and not the String "1".

Please check this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-464